# Нужна ли запятая после "в Западном краю"?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение

Стлин Нат Альсар был не просто замком, он был символом господства итарков в Западном краю и его падение не означало конца одного единственного замка, оно подтверждало окончание этого господства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Стлин Нат Альсар был не просто замком, он был символом господства итарков в Западном краю, и его падение не означало конца одного-единственного замка, оно подтверждало окончание этого господства.***

Сложное предложение состоит из четырех простых предложений с бессоюзной и союзной связью. Запятая ставится перед сочинительным союзом И – там нет общих элементов, отменяющих запятую.

По смыслу союз И делит предложение на два сообщения, но  отношения между предложениями не обозначены  в структуре и интонации  достаточно четко и выразительно. Можно предложить следующую редакцию предложения:

*Стлин Нат Альсар был не просто замком **– он был символом господства итарков в Западном краю**,  и его падение **не означало** конца одного-единственного замка, **но подтверждало** окончание этого господства.*

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Тире ставится для обозначения противопоставления  вместо запятой (был не просто замком, но был символом господства).
2. Во второй части сложного предложения  использованы однородные сказуемые (падение не означало, но подтверждало).
3. Повтор слова «замок», его хорошо бы заменить синонимом.

Comment: Sharon, приветствую! *Одного-единственного* надо бы с дефисом.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Александр!  Спасибо!  А это я специально проверяю вашу внимательность, чтобы вы с нами поговорили (шутка, конечно).  И ссылочку не приведете, а то я не помню, где правило искать.  Пожалуйста.

Comment: https://gramota.me/odin-edinstvennyiy-ili-odin-edinstvennyiy-kak-pish

Comment: Мне бы из Розенталя...  А то я и сайта такого не знаю, а они тоже ссылок на дают.  Но если у вас нет под рукой, то не буду вас отвлекать, потом  найду.

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151

Comment: А это же про тире, а у нас дефис.

Comment: Я подумал, что про одного-единств. не надо, а надо по существу вопроса. :)

Comment: Интересная мысль...  Я нашла "один-единственный"  в словаре, но думала, что  у Розенталя есть в разделе http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=104#pp104   Но там нет. Ладно, хватит пока словаря.  Спасибо!